# redux-promise use 'then()' after dispatching action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to delete a post. I'm using redux-promise as middleware. 
My action looks like this:

```
export function deletePost(id) {
    const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}?apiKey=${API_KEY}`)

    return {
        type: DELETE_POST,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

Then I have a button in my component to trigger action.

```
onDeleteClick() {
        deletePost(id)
        .then(setState({ redirect: true }))
    }
```

The problem is that I can't use 'then()'. I would simply like to redirect user to homepage after deleting post.
Please help me guys.

---

Source code on request.

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const DELETE_POST = 'DELETE_POST';

export const ROOT_URL = 'example.com';
export const API_KEY = 'randomstring';

export function deletePost(id) {
    const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}?apiKey=${API_KEY}`)

    return {
        type: DELETE_POST,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

reducers/post_reducer.js

```
import {  DELETE_POST } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], post: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
            return state.all.filter(post => post !== action.payload.data);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

components/PostShow.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPost, deletePost } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

class PostsShow extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            redirect: false
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPost(this.props.match.params.id)
    }

    onDeleteClick() {
        deletePost(this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }))
    }


    render() {

        if(!this.props.post) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        if(this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to='/'/>
        }

        return (

            <div className='blog-post container'>
                <h3>{this.props.post.title}</h3>
                <h6>Categories: {this.props.post.categories}</h6>
                <p>{this.props.post.content}</p>
                <Link to='/'><button className='btn btn-primary'>Back</button></Link>
                { this.props.user
                ? <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}>Delete</button> 
               : null }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        post: state.posts.post,
        user: state.user
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost }) (PostsShow)
```

Comment: Why can't you use `then`? `request` is the promise right? Therefore `deletePost(id).request.then(...)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [redux-promise source code](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise/blob/ae01607ce357e383edaf18defdc914a3e61f6bba/src/index.js), it looks like it *should* return the chained promise:

```
return isPromise(action.payload)
  ? action.payload.then(
      result => dispatch({ ...action, payload: result }),
      error => {
        dispatch({ ...action, payload: error, error: true });
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    )
  : next(action);
```

So, I would assume that you could chain off of the dispatch.

That said, your snippet has a couple potential issues.  If that's in a component, then where is `deletePost` coming from?  You're also not using `this` in front of `setState`.  Assuming that `deletePost` is a bound-up action creator, this example should be correct:

```
onDeleteClick() {
    this.props.deletePost(id)
        .then(() => this.setState({redirect : true});
}
```

Comment: my deletePost(id) is in actions/index.js

Ive tried your version of onDeleteClick() and I have an error ".then() is not a function"

Comment: Is `deletePost` actually bound up so that it dispatches when called?  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: when I remove the line of code with ".then()" from onDeleteClick function everything is working fine. Action is working and post is deleted. Ive read that only Redux-thunk  gives us control over Redux's dispatch() method, which is responsible for sending every fired action to all of our reducers. This allows us to call actions from within action creators in an asynchronous way. I guess I have to use Redux-thunk then.

Comment: No - any middleware can modify the return value of `dispatch`.  For `redux-thunk`, it returns the result of the thunk function.  Based on the `redux-promise` source, I would expect the promise to be returned from the dispatch.  Just for kicks, try doing `const result = this.props.deletePost(id); console.log(result);`.  I'm still not sure you're actually dispatching the `deletePost` method - it sounds like you're just calling it without dispatching.

Comment: I uploaded more code. I dont know what you mean by calling without dispatching. I mean I call action creator and than action creator call reducers and reducers update the state. This is how I understand it

Comment: Aha.  Yeah, your method isn't calling `this.props.deletePost` - you're calling the unbound imported version of `deletePost()`.  Because that function has the AJAX call, it's still deleting the item on your server, but it's not actually dispatching an action.  Change your `onDeleteClick()` method to be the same as my example and see what happens.